# System of stochastic equations

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I want to know if this system of SDE: $$dX_{t}=b(X_{t})dt+\sigma( X_{t}) dB_{t}$$ 
                                                                       $$dY_{t}=b_{0}(Y_{t})dt+\sigma( Y_{t}) dB_{t}$$
at what conditions on drifts the law of diffusions are absolutly continu each other?
What's happen when coefficients of diffusions are different and same drifts?
NB: B is standard brownian motion.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clearly explain what do you want?

Comment: @Behrouz, I want to know condition of existence for solution.